# How do you prepare an image for a smaller density screen?

Tags: android, image

I initially built an Android app and threw all of my images in the drawable-hdpi resource directory and now I'm going back and making the necessary changes/additions so that the app is supported on all screen sizes and densities.

How do I go about taking all of my images and making them 'less dense'?  My first guess is to load them into Gimp or Photoshop and scale them down to a smaller resolution.  Is this all I need to do?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I go about taking all of my
>   images and making them 'less dense'?
>   My first guess is to load them into
>   Gimp or Photoshop and scale them down
>   to a smaller resolution. Is this all I
>   need to do?

Yes, that's all. The scaling performed by such programs is way better looking than Android's automatic scaling.

The dpi values are:

- ldpi = 120 dpi
- mdpi = 160 dpi
- hdpi = 240 dpi

so if you have hdpi images you can scale them to 66% and obtain mdpi images, or 50% to get ldpi images.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question a bit more specifically.  All my images, though, are in the drawable-hdpi folder and I believe that for those, I scaled them by making them all like 800x840 resolution, instead of making them 240 dpi.  Should I redo all of those too?

Comment: Actually, to be even more precise, I don't know if you have GIMP or not, but if I go to Image>Scale Image, do I change the width/height in pixels, or the x and y resolution in pixels?  Right now my image is height/width = 150 150 pixels, and the x y resolution is 300, 300 pixels per inch.  What those values be for ldpi, mdpi, and hdpi?

Comment: @PetrakovichJ the image's dpi is ignored by Android (yes I have GIMP). 800x840 images are quite huge and they're probably getting scaled down even in hdpi. If they're just elements of the UI (say a button, a logo...) and you know the exact pixels it's going to take (you could take a screenshot from the device) you might want to first scale them down to the exact size, it will take less memory and will look better (especially true for PNG).

Comment: @bigstones My first statement was incorrect as I was just going by memory, so after looking at all my images in the drawable-hdpi folder,  all of them are the right size for the phone I was testing them on.  For example, I have a logo that is 400 px wide (my phones screen is 480 px wide upright).  But I believe what I was doing was making all of the image's resolutions equal to the phone's  exact resolution (800x480).  Should I be making them (for example, 160x160 resolution for mdpi)?

Comment: @PetrakovichJ you should just scale them down to the corresponding percentage. If the layout is flexible enough they'll fit, at least in standard display resolutions. Be sure to test them in various emulators with different display resolutions.

Comment: @bigstones:  I have a feeling that my images should never have been in the hdpi folder in the first place.  Is this so?  Here is my situation:  I developed this app JUST for my phone, a Droid 1 (high density, normal screen)  I got a bunch of images (logos, buttons) from a company and I scaled them all to be the correct appearing size when tested for my Droid, but I threw all of them in the hdpi folder.  Why? I don't know, because the Droid is high density, but the screen SIZE is normal.  Now I want to fix everything so I can start making this app work on small, normal, and large sized screens.

Comment: @PetrakovichJ on API >= 4 if you put resources in drawable-hdpi or another they'll get scaled automatically depending on the dpi. If you used dip's in layouts definitions, they might be just ready. Have you tried your app in emulators with different sizes?

Comment: @PetrakovichJ the -hdpi qualifier only tells your Droid that those are the resources that will fit him. Yet will tell an mdpi phone that to use those resources it will have to scale them down to 66% (and look ugly)

Comment: @bigstones:  I just did, for all the common sizes, and what happens is all the images stay the exact same size, but the layout gets chopped off at the bottom for each smaller size.  Since I designed the app for a Droid 1 (480x854), it only looks proper on that size (normal-hdpi) so are my images in the right folder for my phone? if so, do I really just have to scale them down 66% and 50% for mdpi and ldpi, respectively? and throw them in the proper folder?

Comment: @bigstones:  They do scale down but they don't necessarily look that ugly (that I can tell from the emulator) probably since they aren't very complex graphics.  They just don't scale to a smaller size.  I also don't have any of the <supports-screens> stuff in the manifest, should I?

Comment: @PetrakovichJ <supports-screens> defaults are fine if your're on API >= 4 as you seem to be. The problem of the chopped bottom can be solved by redesigning the layout to take that into account, or by using also -long and -notlong qualifiers to make specific resources. (usually ldpi and mdpi are not long, hdpi might be both). You might also want to use RelativeLayouts and have your images stretched (or use 9patch and shapes).

Comment: I just posted a screen shot, is this still relavent?  My manager is still requiring me to make images for the smaller densities, which I believe I just need to scale them down by 66 and 50 percent, right?  I can't really tell what is going on.

Comment: @bigstones: When you say "redesigning the layout to take that into account", do you mean making a separate layout and putting it in a layout-small etc. folder?

Comment: @PetrakovichJ on making smaller density images: yes, it's about making scaled copies and putting them in their own drawable-*dpi folders.

Comment: @PetrakovichJ on redesigning the layout: if the one you have now doesn't fit, you have two solutions: modify it to be self-adaptable (using relative layouts, 9patches and shapes, scrollviews), or make a new one for -notlong screens (as opposed to -long). -long/-notlong take into account only width/height ratio, not size or dpi. The choice is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about adapting your image to different screen sizes and densities. Also check out the [UI Guidlines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) for icons and such. It gives you exact pixel width by height of an image in the different screen densities. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets) gives EXACT pixel densities. You have to scale down your image and put it in a different folder in your res directory, in your case: put it in the drawable-ldpi folder in res

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have read/am reading through that several times and I can't find the exact answer to my question.  I'm not sure if I should be scaling down the resolution of the image in a photo editing program or what.

Comment: That's closer, but that seems to be only for icons, not general graphics and images within your app.